# Using psycopg2 on Windows I get unwanted debug messages

Tags: python, windows, command-line, psycopg2

everybuddy.

I've installed psycopg2 from the package psycopg2-2.5.1.win32-py2.6-pg9.2.4-release.exe found in the site http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/.
I can import it and connect to a database, but when I run my scripts on the command-line (both, standard and Cygwin) I get unwanted messages printed to stderr.

For example:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="42.42.42.42", port=5432, database="myDB", user="myUser", password="********")
if conn is None:
    sys.exit("Connection failed")
print "Connection successful"
```

Prints the following:

```
DEBUG:  CommitTransaction
DEBUG:  name: unnamed; blockState:       STARTED; state: INPROGR, xid/subid/cid: 0/1/0, nestlvl: 1, children:
Connection successful
```

I've been unable to turn those messages off. I searched in Google but couldn't find anything relevant, and I also tried changing the config of the standard logging module, in case some of that was being used, but still to no avail.

Does anybody know how to prevent this messages?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this build was made with `PSYCOPG_DEBUG` flag set, which should not be the case for a release build after looking at table at http://www.stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/ (note the last column `Debug Build (--define PSYCOPG_DEBUG)`). However it looks like you have `PSYCOPG_DEBUG` environment variable set. If this is the case then unsetting it should prevent these debug messages to be emitted.

From psycopg2.txt

> ## Creating a debug build
>
> In case of problems, Psycopg can be configured to emit detailed debug
>   messages, which can be very useful for diagnostics and to report a
>   bug. In order to create a debug package:
>
> - Download and unpack the Psycopg source package.
> - Edit the "setup.cfg" file adding the "PSYCOPG_DEBUG" flag to the   "define" option.
> - *Compile and install* the package.
> - Set the "PSYCOPG_DEBUG" variable:
>
>   $ export PSYCOPG_DEBUG=1
> - Run your program (making sure that the "psycopg2" package imported   is the one you just compiled and not e.g. the system one): you will
>     have a copious stream of informations printed on stdout.

Comment: Hello Piotr. Thanks for replying. I suspected the same thing, and also checked the column, and no, it shouldn't be a debug version. I also tried issuing the command set PSYCOPG_DEBUG=0 and then calling the python script, but it didn't help. (Remember I'm on Windows, so export and make compile, make install, etc are not available).

Answer (score 0):

Those messages are from Postgres itself.  The second one is a DEBUG3
message in the module `backend/access/transam/xact.c`.  I'd look at the
logging settings in your `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Yeap! Indeed, editing the postgresql.conf on the server and changing the value of client_min_messages to error suppresses the unwanted messages. But what happens if it's a server that I don't have privileged access to?